# Apply constraint conditionally

Tags: 8, forms

I've just started to use Drupal 8's Entity Validation API and I'm applying constraints to entities in the following way using `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter`:

```
MYMODULE_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {

  switch ($bundle) {
    case 'example_content_type':
      $overlay_text = $fields['field_example_text']; 
      $overlay_text->addConstraint('NotNull');
        break;
  }
}
```

This successfully prevents the an instance of this content type being created if no value is entered in the `field_example_text`.

However, in this content type, I'm using conditional fields. In this scenario, I would only want to apply the `NotNull` constraint to `field_example_text` if another field, `field_colors`, a text list checkbox field where the user can check any number of options, has a certain value (e.g. 'Green') checked.

Conditional fields is hiding and showing dependent fields nicely based on which values in `field_colors` are checked, but I need to set these fields as not null via the constraints only when `field_colors` has a particular value. Is this possible?

Comment: You may check out this contribution https://philfrilling.com/blog/2018-09/custom-validation-multiple-dependent-entity-fields-drupal-8. Gives you access to the whole entity for your validation.